# How to Create, Read and Write a yaml file in typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, fs

How should I create, read and write a yaml file from typescript?

I want to take yaml input from the user in a code editor and then create a yaml file with XYZ name and save that yaml code newly created file.

Currently, I am trying to use the below code in Editor.tsx

```
const fs = require('browserify-fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

let data = "adijfvbkhbivebveryvb"
let yamlStr = yaml.safeDump(data);

fs.writeFile('/home/ubuntu/mainread.txt', yamlStr, 'utf8', (error: any, yamlStr: string) => {        
(54)   console.log(yamlStr);
   if (error) {
     console.log(error);
   } else {
(58)     console.log(yamlStr);
(59)     console.log('File created successfully');
   }
});

fs.readFile('/home/ubuntu/mainread.txt', 'utf-8', (error: any, data: any) => {
   if (error) {
     console.log(error);
   } else {
(67)     console.log(data);
   }
});

fs.writeFile('/home/ubuntu/main.txt', yamlStr, function() {
(72)  console.log('File created successfully');
});

fs.readFile('/home/ubuntu/main.txt', 'utf-8', function(err: any, data: any) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
   } else {
(79)     console.log(data);
   }
});
```

But doesn't work for me means if we check /home/ubuntu then no new file was created. The console output was as follows:

```
Editor.tsx:67 adijfvbkhbivebveryvb
Editor.tsx:79 adijfvbkhbivebveryvb
Editor.tsx:54 undefined
Editor.tsx:58 undefined
Editor.tsx:59 File created successfully
Editor.tsx:72 File created successfully
```

I am missing something in the above code because the file was not created at the given location?

Comment: It works as expected. What do you mean by not working?

Comment: But the file is not created at a particular location.